# CSS scale not scaling from center

Tags: html, css, scale, css-transforms

I am using scale to enlarge an element on hover, and it was working fine until I added transform:translate(-50%,-50%); . Then it started to scale the element from the bottom right, not from the center.
Here is my code:

```css
.skyimage{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  top:150px;
  transition:.5s;
  background:transparent;
}


.skyimage:hover{
  transform:scale(1.2) translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you show code snippet or sandbox (jsfiddle, codepen)?

Comment: Ive been working with an HTML file, but I could send you a video of it if thats possible

Comment: move the `scale` transform to **after** the `translate` ... order matters.

Comment: Yes, worked, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Meaning of transform: translate(-50%,-50%) is :-

-move me leftwards by 50% of my width, along the x-axis, and

-move me upwards by 50% of my height, along the y-axis

hence this will not zoom the image from the center, for that scale is enough

Comment: If I just do transform:scale(1.2);, the element will move left and downward when I hover over it.

Comment: So adding the transform translate does help, but it still looks a bit weird.

Comment: if possible upload the full code and remove translate command from .skyimage also

Comment: the full code is over 300 lines